# neovim [coc.nvim] build/inderx.js not found, please install dependencies and compile coc.nvim : yarn install

Tags: javascript, node.js, neovim

I trying to build, yarn build
but it shows me

```
yarn run v1.22.17
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/darth/.config/nvim/plug-config"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should run `yarn install` in coc.nvim directory.

Comment: problem-solve, I tried reinstall and run yarn-install

Comment: `yarn install` after switching to the `release` branch as stated on the readme

Comment: If you are using `Packer`, coc.nvim is in `~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/coc.nvim` otherwise if you are using `vim-plug`, it is in `~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/coc.nvim`

Answer (score 28):

I resolved the errby running the command below on nevoim.

```
:call coc#util#install()
```

Comment: better than the accepted answer imo

Answer (score 9):

The error is due to the fact that COC is **missing** some dependencies to function.

- Navigate to the directory `\nvim\plugged\coc.nvim`
- Use your package manager: `npm install` or `yarn install`

**Restart** your **VIM** or **NEOVIM**.

Comment: in macOS that's in `~/.vim/bundle/coc.nvim`

Comment: I'd also do `yarn build` after install

Comment: on linux, `find -type d -name "coc.nvim"` if it's in a peculiar location.

Comment: MacOS: `cd ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/coc.nvim` then `yarn` or `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

use release branch if you dont want to build over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

resolved on mac by npm install

check the correct path:

> cd ~/.vim/bundle/coc.nvim
> .   cd: no such file or directory: /Users/pawankumar/.vim/bundle/coc.nvim
>
> cd ~/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/
>
> npm install

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who is also dumb like me you're supposed to go to `C:\Users\user\Appdata\Local\nvim-data\plugged\coc.nvim\` because coc.nvim is a directory apparently. Then you run `yarn install` or `npm install` and that should install everything necessary for coc to run properly

Answer (score 1):

On windows navigate to your *C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\nvim-data\plugged\coc.nvim* file and run `yarn install`

Answer (score 1):

###### [ Update : 1st July 2023 ]

###### For anyone running WSL 2 following the below steps worked for me.

- Go to your home path i.e type cd ~ & then install nodejs by entering `$ sudo apt install nodejs`

  - then check the node version using `node -v`

*if your node version < 14 then follow the below:*

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

- by performing the 3 commands you must be able to update node to the latest version, when you again do node -v you will see node is > v 14.

*if node version > 14 then continue below*

Now you need to make sure you have NPM / YARN installed in the path: `~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/coc.nvim`
usually coc.nvim is located here but in case if you cannot find it then there is an easy way:

- go to home cd ~, then enter `explorer.exe .` this will open a file explorer of your WSL 2 file tree, on the search bar just enter coc.nvim & search for the location.

to install NPM / YARN we just need to enter `sudo apt install npm` or `sudo apt install yarn`

*Note: installing YARN did not work for me, So I installed NPM (takes a few minutes to install)*

after this i performed npm install in the same path & that's it.it fixed my error.

---

###### also please note that I encountered this error while installing some packages to customizing my neovim.